# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node' on python 3.8

Tags: python, node.js, pycharm, python-3.8, nvm

I'm hitting this error when trying to run python 3.8 code on pycharm.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'

I'm using an anaconda3 virtual env in 3.8 and running node --version in terminal returns v16.16.

It's failing on this lib:
File "/home/[user]/anaconda3/envs/[venv]/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 260, in start
self._process = subprocess.Popen(

(extract of line that it's failing on in the lib:
...
**jsii_node = environ.get("JSII_NODE", "node")** ...

Any ideas?

I've checked the node install location, Whereis node, which node. and they both show as being present.

node: /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node /home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node

Comment: Well, the failing code seems to be looking for an environment variable. Try running `export JSII_NODE=/usr/bin/node` in Bash (or, if that doesn't work, put it in `~/.bashrc` and restart PyCharn). Not sure this will work, but give it a shot.